# Cannot get all permutations in Python function with itertools

Tags: python-3.x

I am looking to the a list for all possible combinations in all possible sequences for the following these numbers [1, 2, 3, 4] and length 3. I got the code half working but it is not giving me all desired outputs such as it is missing for example combinations such as: 121, 132, 131 etc. What is missing?

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement 

# Get all combinations of [1, 2, 3, 4] and length 3 
comb = combinations_with_replacement([1, 2, 3, 4], 3) 

# Print the obtained combinations 
for i in list(comb): 
    print (i) 

OUT:
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 1, 3)
(1, 1, 4)
(1, 2, 2)
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 4)
(1, 3, 3)
(1, 3, 4)
(1, 4, 4)
(2, 2, 2)
(2, 2, 3)
(2, 2, 4)
(2, 3, 3)
(2, 3, 4)
(2, 4, 4)
(3, 3, 3)
(3, 3, 4)
(3, 4, 4)
(4, 4, 4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems you are looking for the all permutations. You could use `product` from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import product
a = [1,2,3,4]
list(product(*[a]*3))
```